# Display on screen volume overlay - macOS

Tags: macos, swift3

I am writing an app that handles volume control of various audio devices.
I have all the code in place to control the volume but I am not getting any visual feedback of this happening on screen. 
Is there a way in macOS to display the the current system volume overlay, like what you get when changing the volume with the keyboard?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Thanks.